# PHP / MySQL Multiple substrings?

Tags: php, mysql, substring

I have a field in my table that contains numbers for instance: `7121968` - what I would like to do is add a `.` before the last four and before the last 6 digits so that it looks like: `7.12.1968`.
I can use substring to just show the last 4 digits etc - is what i am trying to do possible using substring and if so could someeone point me in the right direction? thanks.

Comment: Did you store a date there or are the numbers pure coincidence?

Comment: that was pure coincidence - should add i currently have
substr(field, -4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, 1), '.', SUBSTRING(<column>, 2, 2), '.', SUBSTRING(<column>, 4)) FROM <table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = '7121968';
$x2 = substr($x,0,-6) . '.' . substr($x,-6,2) . '.' . substr($x,-4);
```